# Applying a function to vectors (subseted row?) of elementes in a matrix

Tags: r, apply

If i have a matrix sucha as

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(30), nrow=5, ncol=6)
x

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]       [,6]
[1,] -2.6564554 -0.1719174 -1.7631631  1.0351035 -0.85090759  0.7581632
[2,] -2.4404669  1.2146747  0.4600974 -0.6089264 -2.41420765 -0.7267048
[3,]  1.3201133  1.8951935 -0.6399949  0.5049551  0.03612261 -1.3682810
[4,] -0.3066386 -0.4304691  0.4554501 -1.7170087  0.20599860  0.4328180
[5,] -1.7813084 -0.2572694  0.7048373 -0.7844590 -0.36105730 -0.8113932
```

i would like to generate a matrix Y that contains the slope of each set of 3 data points in each row, so elements `Y[1,1]` and `Y[1,2]` of my new matrix would be something like this:

```
Y[1,1]=lm(x[1,1:3]~c(1,2,3))$coefficient[2]
Y[1,2]=lm(x[1,2:4]~c(1,2,3))$coefficient[2]
```

i know how to do this with a for, which is ok for small data, but doing it on a dataset with over a million rows its almost inmpossible this way. My issue with the `apply()` function is that i know how to apply the function on each row, column or individual element of the dataset, but not to sets of 3 elements. hope im clear. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `rollapply` function from `zoo` that seems to do what you want.

```
library(zoo)
rr <- t(rollapply(t(x), by.column=TRUE, width=3,
                  FUN=function(z) coef(lm(z ~ c(1,2,3)))[2]))
```

It seems like there might be an extra transpose in there, but I couldn't figure out how to get rid of it...

Comment: or making use of the defaults: `t(rollapply(t(x), 3, function(z) coef(lm(z ~ I(1:3)))[2]))`

Answer (score 1):

I created a looping function over each row to calculate the coefficient for each set of three elements.

```
mylm = function (x) {
  v=vector("numeric", length(x)-2)
  for (i in 1:(length(x)-2)) {
    v[i]=lm(x[i:(i+2)]~c(1,2,3))$coefficient[2]
  }
  v
}
Y = t(apply(x, 1, FUN=mylm))
Y
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.2655043 -0.3789681 0.2305446 -0.8279703
[2,] -0.1925491 -0.4061229 0.3647903 -0.1093176
```

Comment: Thanks for the the help @pcantalupo